# How does pointer dereferencing work?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

```
#define SWAP_PTRS(a, b) do { void *t = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = t; } while (0)

Node* MergeLists(Node* list1, Node* list2) 
{
  Node *list = NULL, **pnext = &list;

  if (list2 == NULL)
    return list1;

  while (list1 != NULL)
  {
    if (list1->data > list2->data)
      SWAP_PTRS(list1, list2);

    *pnext = list1;
    pnext = &list1->next;
    list1 = *pnext;
  }

  *pnext = list2;
  return list;
}
```

This code is from here, the chosen answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348374/merging-two-sorted-lists).

I cannot understand 3 lines here:

```
*pnext = list1;
pnext = &list1->next;
list1 = *pnext;
```

Can anyone kindly help me? Explain it for me?

Edited:  Can I change these 2 lines:

```
pnext = &list1->next;
list1 = *pnext;
```

to

```
 list = list-> next;
```

Comment: This isn't C++; the SWAP_PTRS macro won't work in C++.  (It counts on the implicit conversion of void* to any pointer type, which isn't present in C++.)

Comment: thank you for reminding. I've changed tag to C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the start: You have two lists and a new list head which you will be returning. pnext points to that initially.

The code aims to do as few pointer reassignments as possible, so tries to keep the initial 'next' pointers of the input lists intact.

```
list1          pnext->list->Null
|
V
o->o->o...

list2
|
V
o->o->o...
```

Swap is there to ensure that the smaller element is the first of list1. What those lines does is:

Going step by step:

```
*pnext = list1;
```

Gets *pnext (which is list before the first iteration) to point to the node containing the smallest element:

```
list1
|
V
o->o->o...
^
|
list<-pnext

list2
|
V
o->o->o...
```

.

```
pnext = &list1->next;
```

Is the tricky part, as noted before & operator has low precedence. It's also hard to display graphically for it actually looks into part of a Node construct. Something like this though:

```
list1
|
V
o---->o->o...
^     ^
|     |
list  x<-pnext

list2
|
V
o->o->o...
```

where x is the next pointer of the o which list1 points to.

```
list1 = *pnext;
```

Advances the list1 head, as its first element is processed.

```
   list1<-pnext
   |
   V
o->o->o->...
^
|
list

list2
|
V
o->o->o->...
```

You have nothing to do with list from here on, for you want to return it as the head of the merged list.

The invariant there is pnext points to where the last processed element's next points to, which is where the smallest element from list1-2 should go. The interesting stuff happens with swaps, try to work out the exact proceedings yourself (hard to draw like this, and good exercise to understand what ** does). I might add it if I find a good way to draw it.

You cannot use `list = list-> next;` for it would do something like this:

```
   list1
   |
   V
o->o->o->...
   ^
   |
   list

list2
|
V
o->o->o->...
```

Which means you lose that lonely o (and everything else eventually as the loop progresses).

edit: The `*pnext = list2;` at the end does this:

Loop termination (state before the said statement):

```
         list1<-pnext
         |
         V
o->o->o->null
^
|
list

      o->o->o->...
      ^
      |
      list2
```

After the statement:

```
         list1
         |
         V              
o->o->o  Null
^     |
|     |
list  |
      V
      o->o->o->...
      ^
      |
      list2<-pnext
```

That statement appends the remaining list to the end of the list. Then Node* list is returned, pointing to the head of the merged list.

edit2:

And all the way, pnext would be better represented like this:

```
         list1
         |
         V              
o->o->o  Null
^     |
|     |<-pnext
list  |
      V
      o->o->o->...
      ^
      |
      list2
```

Which means it points to the next pointer of the last processed node.

Comment: than you @mcyalcin so much! This is a damn good explanation. Thanks a lot! I got it

Comment: hi @mcyalcin, one more question, what about "*pnext = list2;"? Is this line modify the "list" pointer? little confused here now. thanks!

Comment: @Josh You mean the *pnext=list2; at the end I guess. That is after the loop terminates, which means one of the lists is empty, so the remaining list will be appended to the end of the list. That assignment has nothing to do with the Node* list (you are presumably quite far away from that). I'll try drawing that in an edit.

Comment: @Josh Now that I think about it pnext should actually point to the arrow for clarity's sake (which is what I had meant when I was saying it was actually pointing to a part of node construct. Think of it as pointing to the arrow. Ah well, another tiny edit.

Comment: thank you mcyaclin. I think I finally understand this code. :)

Answer (score 2):

`pnext` is a *pointer to a pointer to a `Node`*.

"`*pnext`" means you are working with the value pointed to by `pnext`. Thus:

```
*pnext = list1;
```

means that whatever pointer `pnext` was pointing to is now pointing to the same thing as `list1`.

---

The next line should be bracketed for clarity to this:

```
pnext = &(list1->next);
```

`list1->next` means you are accessing the `next` attribute of what `list1` is pointing too, and the `&` means to take the address of that element. The essentially means you are making `pnext` point to a pointer to the next element.

---

The last line:

`list1 = *pnext;`

means that you taking the value pointed to by `pnext` and assigning it to `list1`.

Comment: can I change these 2 lines:
 pnext = &list1->next;
 list1 = *pnext;  to list = list-> next;

Answer (score 1):

`list1` is of type `Node*` and  `pnext` is of type `Node**` meaning it should hold the address of a variable whose type is `Node*`.

```
*pnext = list1;
```

When you dereference `pnext`, you get `Node*`. So, this assignment is correct.

```
pnext = &list1->next;
```

Here `->` has a higher precedence over `&`. So, it returns a pointer's address( i.e., address of a Node* type )

```
list1 = *pnext;
```

This is just the opposite of the first statement. Dereferencing `pnext` gives `Node*` which can be assigned to `list1`.

---

Yes, you can change this( i.e., logically they does the same thing ) -

```
pnext = &list1->next;
list1 = *pnext;
```

to

```
list1 = list1->next ;
```

But, you have a statement -

```
 *pnext = list2;
```

If `pnext` wasn't initialized as in the two step sequence, dereferencing an uninitialized pointer( i.e., `*pnext` ) would result segmentation fault. That is the reason.

Comment: can I change these 2 lines: pnext = &list1->next; list1 = *pnext; to list = list-> next;?

Comment: so why the coder in that post gave such a mysterious code??? And you can check that post, other solution also followed this style... I am not sure I was right about this change.

Comment: @Josh No, you cannot! You'd lose the pointer to the head of the list which you are returning, which is the whole point of the code. The code is actually quite elegant there. I'll write up an explanation (I reckon it would require some figures to be clear).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install visual studio express edition.
Once you debug the program in VS-2012, you can simply hover the mouse on the pointer and it'll show you the contents by dereferencing the address.