# How to improve my code of Merge two sorted link list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, mergesort

I received a interview question from Microsoft by email, it is quite simple, just merge two sorted linked list and make sure there's no identical data.

I implemented it in Java:

https://gist.github.com/cb4cd94f74cff1d2bd03

At first i want to use recursion but i think it's not efficient when the list is too large. So i use *while* instead.

But when i send it back, there's no response anymore, so i wonder is there anything wrong in my code ? How should i improve it ?

Thanks !

Comment: What about the case when you have an empty linked list you want to add to a non-empty linked list? wouldn't you want to return the non-empty? Also the multiple exit points/`while(true)` of the loop bother me.

Comment: Were you given any starting code? You seem to have merged two `Node` classes, whereas I would have probably started from `java.util.LinkedList`. I also notice that your method is not idempotent as it modifies the inputs. Your code is also hard to read and understand. I'd try and make it a little simpler.

Comment: Thanks @Qwerky, They didn't ask me to avoid build-in libraries, but i decided to avoid them, now i think its not a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if one of the lists is `null` then the `RuntimeException` is thrown?
I think that if one of the lists is `null` and the other is not you can just return the second one.
Am I missing something?
Anyway, if the input is not as you expected there is no reason to throw `RuntimeException`, the `InvalidArgumentException` fits better.

```
if (head1 == null || head2 == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Unavaliable source data sets, please make sure both of the two lists are not null");
    }
```

Moreover, your code is not optimal.
I would go for something more concise: (Pay attention on using [accessor methods](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/strings/accessors.html) instead of accessing `Node` class members directly - it is considered bad  because you are breaking the encapsulation)

```
Node MergeLists(Node list1, Node list2) {
    if (list1 == null) {
       return list2;
    } 
    if (list2 == null) {
        return list1;
    }  

    if (list1.getData() < list2.getData()) {
        list1.setNext(MergeLists(list1.getNext(), list2));
        return list1;
    } else {
        if (list1.getData() != list2.getData()) {
            list2.setNext(mergeLists(list2.getNext(), list1));
            return list2;
        }

        Node tail = mergeLists(list2.getNext(), list1.getNext());
        tail = (tail == null) ? null : tail.getNext();

        list2.setNext(tail);
        return list2;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you make sure there's no identical data in the merged list ?

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your algorithm to account for lists like this:

```
 1 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8  -> 12
 2 -> 3 -> 9 -> 10 -> 19
```

with your algorithm:

```
1:    1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> 12        Node1: 1, Node2: 2
2:    1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> 12   Node1: 2, Node2: 3
3:    1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> 12   Node1: 3, Node2: 9  
...
```

With an optimized algorithm you would have seen that 2 -> 3 would fit between 1 -> 4 and pointed 1 at 2 and 3 at 4. Its this set of instructions that makes it so:

```
 ...
 tmp = head2.next;
 head2.next = head1.next;
 head1.next = head2;
 head2 = tmp;
 head1 = head1.next;
 ...
```

See you set `head1.next = head2` then 2 lines later you set `head1 = head1.next`.

Also, it was really difficult reading that and trying to determine what was happening node to node. Your comments were not useful. Maybe something like `//swap the nodes`.

Your while loop could use an exit condition. The multiple exit points is just not good style. Infinite loops are a big no no, they make the understanding/graphing your code much more difficult.

Hope this helps.

edit:
This is what I came up with.

```
public static Node merge(Node node1, Node node2){
    //store head to be returned (the smallest)
    Node masterHead = node1.value > node2.value? node2 : node1;
    //put smaller elements at the beginning
    while(node1 != null && node2.next != null && node1.value > node2.value)
    {   
        Node nextInList2 = node2.next;
        node2.next = node1;
        node1 = node2;
        node2 = nextInList2;
    }
    //merging loop
    while(node1.next != null && node2 != null){
        if(node1.next.value > node2.value)
        {
            //insert node(s) into the array
            Node higherNode = node1.next;
            node1.next = node2;
            //advance until every node being inserted is less that the next
            while(node2.next != null && higherNode.value > node2.next.value){
                node2 = node2.next;
            }
            //point back into the list
            Node nextInList2 = node2.next;
            node2.next = higherNode;
            node2= nextInList2;
        }
        node1 = node1.next;
    }
    if(node1.next == null)
        node1.next = node2;
    return masterHead;
}
```

I didn't test for null arguments, just because it was assumed/I'm not turning this into microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution

```
Public static void merge(Node first, Node second){
    if(first==null) return second;
    if(second==null) return first;

    if(first.data<second.data){
        first.next = merge(first.next, second);
        return first;
    }else{
        second.next = merge(second.next, first);
        return second;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved in another thread by Stefan Haustein!

[Interview: Merging two Sorted Singly Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707352/interview-merging-two-sorted-singly-linked-list)

```
public static Node merge(Node list1, Node list2) {
    if (list1 == null)
        return list2;
    if (list2 == null)
        return list1;

    Node head;
    if (list1.data < list2.data) {
        head = list1;
    } else {
        head = list2;
        list2 = list1;
        list1 = head;
    }
    while (list1.next != null && list2 != null) {
        if (list1.next.data <= list2.data) {
            list1 = list1.next;
        } else {
            Node tmp = list1.next;
            list1.next = list2;
            list2 = tmp;
        }
    }
    if (list1.next == null)
        list1.next = list2;
    return head;
}
```