# How does indirection work in this code?

Tags: algorithm, c, linked-list

I was reading the answer to [Merging two sorted linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348374/merging-two-sorted-linked-lists?rq=1).
The code:

```
#define SWAP_PTRS(a, b) do { void *t = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = t; } while (0)

Node* MergeLists(Node* list1, Node* list2) 
{
  Node *list = NULL, **pnext = &list;

  if (list2 == NULL)
    return list1;

  while (list1 != NULL)
  {
    if (list1->data > list2->data)
      SWAP_PTRS(list1, list2);

   // What does the following piece of code do ?
    *pnext = list1;  // ??
    pnext = &list1->next; // ??
    list1 = *pnext;     // ?? 
  }

  *pnext = list2;
  return list;
}
```

I am not able to understand how the double pointer is working here, how the values are changed ?

Comment: What happens when you step through it in your debugger, watching the variable values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pnext is a pointer to a pointer of Node and is meant to hold the address of the `next` field of the last node

so the first line sets the pointer to the next node (either list or the previous `node->next`)

the second line sets pnext to the `next` field of the current node

the third line advances list1 after just dealing with the head of it using the just assigned pnext for a micro-optimization that avoids dereferencing list1 again

you can also write it in terms of node->next:

```
#define SWAP_PTRS(a, b) do { void *t = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = t; } while (0)

Node* MergeLists(Node* list1, Node* list2) 
{
  Node *list = NULL, *node ;

  if (list2 == NULL)
    return list1;

  if (list1->data > list2->data)
    SWAP_PTRS(list1, list2);

  node=list=list1;

  list1=list1->next;

  while (list1 != NULL)
  {
    if (list1->data > list2->data)
      SWAP_PTRS(list1, list2);

    node->next = list1;  

    node = list1->next; 
    list1 = list1->next;     
  }

  node->next = list2;
  return list;
}
```