# Merging and sorting two sorted arrays containing doubles in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, mergesort

So I have two arrays consisting of double numbers, they are sorted.

I would like to most efficiently combine these into one array and have this one array also sorted.

My first thought was that maybe you could simply join them together then use qsort on it, but this wouldn't be that efficient. So maybe instead using merge sort? However, I am kind of lost on how to implement merge sort in C, any ideas?

I am using the code from one of the answers to try merge sorting. I have not made it into its own method just yet, will do that after I have gotten it to work.

```
double partitions[][5] = {{45.0, 5.0, 88.4, 0.4, 44.0}, {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 7.0, 50.0}};
double* res;

int n1 = sizeof(partitions[0])/sizeof(partitions[0][0]);
int n2 = sizeof(partitions[1])/sizeof(partitions[1][0]);
int n3 = n1 + n2;

res = malloc(n3 * sizeof(double));

// Merging starts
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
    if (partitions[0][i] - partitions[1][j] < 0.000001) {
        res[k] = partitions[0][i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    else {
        res[k] = partitions[1][j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}

/* Some elements in array 'arr1' are still remaining
where as the array 'arr2' is exhausted */
while (i < n1) {
    res[k] = partitions[0][i];
    i++;
    k++;
}

/* Some elements in array 'arr2' are still remaining
where as the array 'arr1' is exhausted */
while (j < n2) {
    res[k] = partitions[1][j];
    k++;
    j++;
}

int m;
for (m = 0; m < n3; m++)
    printf("%f \n", res[m]);
```

Comment: so, you don't want a sorting algorithm, you just want a merging algorithm. Let's be clear on that.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that's not a solution. It's not a solution in the sense that it doesn't help OP's C code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348374/merging-two-sorted-linked-lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-Recursive Merge Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557894/non-recursive-merge-sort)

Comment: Surely, this is kinda intuitive?  Taking the largest, or equal, value from the top of the two sorted arrays and storing it in the result?  Or the smallest from the bottom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two sorted linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348374/merging-two-sorted-linked-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the arrays are sorted you only need the merge part of the merge sort which is O(n1+n2) where `n1` is the length of the one array and `n2` is the length of the other array:

For example:

```
void merge(int n1, int n2){ //suppose global arrays arr1,arr2 and result array

      i = 0;
      j = 0;
      k = 0;

    // Merging starts
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (arr1[i] <= arr2[j]) {
            res[k] = arr1[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } 
        else {
            res[k] = arr2[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    /* Some elements in array 'arr1' are still remaining
    where as the array 'arr2' is exhausted */

    while (i < n1) {
        res[k] = arr1[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Some elements in array 'arr2' are still remaining
    where as the array 'arr1' is exhausted */

    while (j < n2) {
        res[k] = arr2[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Also I just note that your arrays contain double so you need to change the condition when comparing two numbers. For example instead of  `if (arr1[i] <= arr2[j])` you need to write  a condition for: `if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])` and then the else part.

Comment: Are the initial vlaues of i,j,k = 0?

Comment: @osk, yes edited the answer watch the part about doubles you can't compare for equality using ==.

Comment: I have two vectors that I'm trying this on, partitions[0] and partitions[1]. I put if (partitions[0][i] - partitions[1][j] < 0.000001) just to test but I'm getting a merged array in return that is not sorted

Comment: I will add it to the op

Comment: You can check my op now, thank you for the help by the way!

Comment: I don't understand the part about comparing doubles. What's wrong with `arr1[i] <= arr2[j]` and how would adding an epsilon help?

Comment: Actually I think you don't need to check for equality so just try  arr1[i] <arr2[j] and then the else part, but in arr1[i] <= arr2[j] see that I removed equality `=` since you can't check with `==` for double equality....

Comment: @coder Yes, you can. There's nothing wrong with `==` or `<=`.

Comment: @ melpomene , what I'm missing here? how could you check if two doubles are equal? (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260776/how-to-compare-double-numbers)

Comment: @coder "*For example, if you are sorting numbers in a list or other data structure, you should not use any tolerance for comparison.*" Did you even read the answer?

Comment: I added your code to my original post @coder, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @melpomene , ok so what you're saying is that you don't need to check for equality?

Comment: @osk - you are stull using `partitions[0][i] - partitions[1][j] < 0.000001`, that's your problem

Comment: @osk,as I said above replace: `partitions[0][i] - partitions[1][j] < 0.000001` with `partitions[0][i] < partitions[1][j] ` (if doubles are equal you don't need to add the condition <0.000001 this will be covered in else part...)

Comment: Ok I realized that my starting arrays were not sorted as they were supposed to be. I just solved it, and yes I am no longer using epsilon. Thank you for the help!